# Dit-on plutôt « Les dernières fois où » ou »Les dernières fois que »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, constructions, formulation, reformulation

Les dernières fois que nous nous sommes vus, tu m’exaspérais avec tes demandes incessantes.

Les dernières fois où nous nous sommes vus, tu m’exaspérais avec tes demandes incessantes.

Devrais-je plutôt (Serait-ce préférable d’) adopter une formulation de rechange du genre « À l’occasion de nos dernières rencontres », « Lors de nos dernières rencontres »?

Il me ferait grand plaisir que vous me présentiez d’autres tournures avec d’autres termes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Où*** après ***fois*** était semble-t-il considéré comme relâché jusqu'à la fin du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle. Littré par exemple condamne *Songez aux fois où il vous a battu* et recommande *Songez aux fois qu'il vous a battu*. D'autres grammairiens semblent rejeter les deux. (cf. Le bon usage §725)

Si tu souhaites préserver le ton soutenu que tu sembles apprécier, tes formulations de rechange seront donc préférables.

*Il me ferait grand plaisir que vous me présentiez d’autres tournures avec d’autres termes.*

En voilà deux :

> Que ne m'avez-vous pas irrité de vos demandes lors de chacune de nos dernières entrevues !

Ou, dans un autre registre :

> Ça fait un moment qu'à chaque fois qu'on se croise, tu me gaves avec tes questions !

<sup>1</sup> <sub>*Que* ne peut cependant pas être utilisé après un pronom : Celles **où** nous nous sommes vus, pas *celles <s>**que**</s> nous nous sommes vus*.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

*que* et *ou* peuvent convenir et s'utilisent dans le langage courant.
Quand il s'agit de rapport au temps, il vaut mieux privilégier **que**
*Il y a **deux** **ans** **que** tu es partie.*
**Chaque fois que** tu perds au jeu

Donc plutôt :
*Les dernières fois **que** ...

Autre formulation :
*A chacune de nos dernières rencontres,
tu m'as exaspéré avec tes demandes sans fin !*